# I’m getting issue while installing npm

Tags: node.js, angular

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_ modules webpack-dev- server \node _modules \ chokidar\node_modules \fsevents): pm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os" "darwin", "arch":"any") (current: ("os": "win32", "arch ipm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node modules \angular- ide\node modules \chokidar\node_modules\fsevents) : pm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os* "darwin", "arch": "any" (current: {"os": "win32", "arch" pm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node _modules \karma \ node _modules \chokidar\node modules \fsevents) : pm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os": "darwin", "arch": "any") (current: ("os* "win32", "arc npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045 npm ERR) argv "C: \Program Files\ Inodejs\Inode.exe" "C: I\Program Files\ Inode js\\node_modules \ Inpm (bin Inpm-cli.js" "install" ppm ERR! node v6.17.1 nom ERR] npm v3.10.10 pm ERR! path C: \1234_HH|\ Forester-Oct-2023 Workspace Agent Portal -12102023\foresters \AgentPortal_Ang2_Base\sre\main \webapp\node modules\-staging \@types \ age.json npm ERR! code ENOTDIR nom ERR] errno -4058 nom ERR! syscall open pm ERR! ENOENT; no such file or directory, open *C: \1234_ HH\Forester-Oct-2023\Workspace \AgentPortal -12102023\foresters \AgentPortal Ang2 Base\sre\maint staging\ @types \geojson-d626295d \package. json* nom ERR! mpm ERR] If you need help, you may report this error at: nom ERR! <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues> nom ERR! Please include the following file with any support request npm ERRI C: \1234_HH\ Forester-Oct -2023 \Workspace \AgentPortal -12102023\foresters \Agent Portal _Ang2_Base \src\main \webapp\npm-debug.1og C: \1234_HH\Forester-Oct-2023\Workspace \AgentPortal-12102023\foresters \AgentPortal_Ang2_Base\src|main\webapp›--Joglevelverbose`

I’m trying to install npm

Comment: Please provide more details about the system where the install is performed and the project. If it's an Angular project, please provide the Angular version. You are using a _very_ old NodeJS & npm version. This can be a problem with more recent versions of Angular.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.